# Laravel validator: complex rule for exists rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a table that looks like this

```
vote_id
voter_email
target_id
vote_date
```

The voter can vote once per day for each `target_id`. I am trying to validate votes and this is what I've got so far

```
['email' => "exists:participants_votes,voter_email,target_id,$targetId,vote_date,$date"];
```

How can I check the date for a range? Is there a way to do it without writing custom code?

There is the `after:date` validator but it has to be in the same scope as `exists:`

Basically something like this: (this sql could be totally wrong though)

```
Select MAX(vote_date) FROM parcitipants_votes WHERE voter_email = ?
```

then I would check if this date is > now - 24 hours.

I'm trying to do it the "right" way by using validator but maybe this is not meant for it...

Note: I cannot just have 1 entry per email with a vote_count, because I need to be storing information such as the vote_date for each vote, even if its from the same person.

Comment: write a custom rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to use the validator for this complex scenario and to just query the database, it was simple and effective.

```
$voteDate = \DB::table('participants_votes')
              ->where('voter_email', '=', $user->email)
              ->where('contest_id', '=', $contestId)
              ->where('target_user_id', '=', $targetId)
              ->where('created_at', '>', new \DateTime('now -24 hours'))
              ->pluck('created_at');
```

voteDate would be null if the email has voted in the past 24 hours.